# How (may?) I export Ada type based on a "new" type from a generic?

Tags: generics, declaration, ada

I'm pretty sure this is a trap for *new* Ada people.  I feel there is something simple needed to get this right.  I have some older code with the declaration for a **Send_Command** procedure with a  **Command_String_Type** type parameter based on the Ada.Strings.Bounded generic module.

***old***

```ada
 -- -- -- command.ads -- -- --

    -- nothing relevant, Send_command is/was internal to module.
     :

 -- -- -- command.adb -- -- --

    -- Type to hold command to send while it is being constructed.
 package Command_String_Type is
      new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length(Max => Command_Max);

     :
     :

 procedure   Send_Command( 
                 Command_String : in Command_String_Type.Bounded_String );
```

This: **Command_String_Type** is used as the parameter type for the Send_Command  procedure this module must export from this module.

My trouble comes when I attempt to declare the Command_String_Type in the modules specification (.**ads**) file.  I can't get the syntax straight to 'export' this type specification for this procedure.

***target***

```ada
 -- -- -- command_interface.ads -- -- --

 package Command_Interface is

      Command_Max : constant := 200;
        :

    -- WANTED ... export Command_String_Type from this module

    -- Type to hold command to send while it is being constructed.
   package Command_String_Type is
        new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length(Max => Command_Max);

     :
     :

   procedure   Send_Command( 
                   Command_String : in Command_String_Type.Bounded_String ); 
     :

 end Command_Interface; -- specification


 -- -- -- command_interface.adb -- -- --

 package body Command_Interface is

         :
   procedure   Send_Command( 
                   Command_String : in Command_String_Type.Bounded_String ) 
   is
   begin
         :
        -- implementation ...
         :
   end Send_Command;

 end Command_Interface; --package
```

Naturally enough the Ada-95 compiler wants a "*Command_String_Type*" as shown above.  Wanted to put the Send_Command procedure in the command_interface package.  And export that for other modules to use.  This procedure depends on the *Command_String_Type*

1. At first I did a straight paste of the package Command_String_Type is new Ada.Strings... construct -- And received errors.

   - That is the code above under the "*target*" heading.
2. I thought that a type declaration in the .ADS file would work because the error complains about "no type" -- Again I have errors.
3. I then also got errors using Subtype.
4. (update... ) Declared *Command_String_Type* as *private* -- Still having compile errors
5. My last effort was to make a Command_String_Type_XX subtype of Command_String_Type with the idea that I could thus expose the subtype in the declaration.

So far I'm none for five.  I've been reading books and looking at training notes, I'm disappointed I can't find some example that 'exports' a string type from a bounded string -- I'm still looking, of course, however I'm beginning to wonder if what I think of as straightforward as it would be in other languages.  Is this possible and permitted with Ada. *Gratitude* in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: What does your code look like? Which errors do you get? A bounded string _is_ a string type, so what do you mean by "'exports' a string type from a bounded string"?  You cannot make `Command_String_Type_XX` a subtype of `Command_String_Type`, because `Command_String_Type` is a *package*, not a type.

Comment: Having moved the declaration to the package spec, did you delete the (now) duplicate of it in the package body?

Comment: You really need to show us the code you’ve tried, particularly for your (1) which was on the right track. I suspect that your problem is indicated by your naming choice, as egilhh said: the *package* name should be `Command_Strings`, or similar, because the bounded string *type* is `Command_Strings.Bounded_String`. On the other hand, you talk about *exporting a string type from a bounded string*, so perhaps you’re looking for `To_String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec you propose looks fine:

```ada
with  Ada.Strings.Bounded;
package Command_Interface is
   Command_Max : constant := 200;
   package Command_String_Type is
     new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length (Max => Command_Max);
   procedure Send_Command
     (Command_String : in Command_String_Type.Bounded_String);
end Command_Interface;
```

and so does the body (this is a demo, of course):

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
package body Command_Interface is
   procedure Send_Command
     (Command_String : in Command_String_Type.Bounded_String) is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Command_String_Type.To_String (Command_String));
   end Send_Command;
end Command_Interface;
```

and now we come to use it. You’ve created the package `Command_String_Type` in the visible part of `Command_Interface`, so you can reference it as `Command_Interface.Command_String_Type`:

```ada
with Command_Interface;
procedure Check_Command_Interface is
begin
   Command_Interface.Send_Command
     (Command_Interface.Command_String_Type.To_Bounded_String ("hello!"));
end Check_Command_Interface;
```

You might think this is all getting a bit verbose. You could shorten the instantiation’s name, e.g.

```ada
   package Command is
     new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Generic_Bounded_Length (Max => Command_Max);
```

or you could use the package renaming trick near the call,

```ada
procedure Check_Command_Interface_2 is
   package CICST renames Command_Interface.Command_String_Type;
begin
   Command_Interface.Send_Command (CICST.To_Bounded_String ("hello!"));
end Check_Command_Interface_2;
```

or you could go overboard and `use`:

```ada
procedure Check_Command_Interface_3 is
   use Command_Interface.Command_String_Type;
begin
   Command_Interface.Send_Command (To_Bounded_String ("hello!"));
end Check_Command_Interface_3;
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon Wright, check 4 is what I need to export this procedure and maintain compatibility with a whole lot of existing code.  Sometimes it comes down to what "fits" with previous efforts.